# C# - Formatting DateTime to Month

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, datetime, drop-down-menu

I am retrieving the DateTime from a db which is coming through in the Dropdown list as the full date and time. What i need is just the month from that DateTime in word format in that drop down list.

As below:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string OnChainChange(string ChainId)
{
    DataTable table = DBHelper.GetMonthList(ChainId.Trim());

    string result = string.Empty;

    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        DateTime thisDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FromDate"].ToString());

        result += new ListItem(thisDate.ToString("MMMM"), thisDate.Month.ToString("MMMM"));
        //result += dr["FromDate"].ToString() + ";";
    }

    return result;
}
```

> LB - This question is different. I am trying to do this as a new listItem. I understand how to convert DateTime int. I would love you to find a duplicate answer to that! :)

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @L.B, the issue is not getting the Month name, instead the issue is `thisDate.Month.ToString("MMMM")`, trying to convert `int`  value using `DateTime` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
thisDate.Month.ToString("MMMM")
```

`DateTime.Month` is of type `int`, if you are trying to add it as a value then simply use

```
thisDate.Month.ToString() //without passing in any parameter
```

If you want value to be Month Name then use:

```
thisDate.ToString("MMMM")
```

instead of passing a parameter to `ToString`, You will end up with all values set to `MMMM`

Comment: wont seem to work :( Your comment makes great sense!

Comment: @ebutlerdeveloper, use `thisDate.Month.ToString()`, what exactly you need as a value in your `ListItem`, Month Number or Month Name ?

Comment: i need the month name

Comment: @ebutlerdeveloper, then use `thisDate.ToString("MMMM")`